# Why is firebase creating a random identifier between parent and child?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm playing around with a firebase web app and having some difficulty diagnosing where something is coming from.

I am trying to simply push some data to my project under the heading of the uid created when authentication takes place. The authentication works fine and it is returning the uid correctly however, when values are passed it seems to be adding a second layer before the actual values.

```
function registerAccount() {
    var firebase = app_firebase;
    var firebaseRef = app_firebase.database();   //database reference
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    uid = user.uid;

    var ref = firebaseRef.ref('User').child(uid);           //referencing node
    var userName = document.getElementById("txtUsernameInput").value;

    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.

        var data = {                             //data being added
            Username: userName,
        }

        window.location = 'myHome.aspx';

     } else {
         // No user is signed in.
         console.log("Cannot get UID");
     }

    ref.push(data);


}
```

I am expecting the data entry to show with the child of user to be the uid taken from the authentication (this is working) then have the passed values immediately in the uid without the seemingly auto generated child between the uid and the values.

Image shows the unwanted field being generated

[See here][1]

Comment: Change `ref.push(data);` to `ref.set(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[André Kool's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916627/andr%c3%a9-kool) suggestion in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55557949/why-is-firebase-creating-a-random-identifier-between-parent-and-child/55558055#comment97816330_55557949):

> Change `ref.push(data);` to `ref.set(data);`

worked.